# 500 Internal server error CakePHP

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, internal-server-error

I uploaded a cakePHP project to the Godaddy server.

I have also seen this link. But not solve the error:-

[500 internal server error occured in CakePHP 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32188611/500-internal-server-error-occured-in-cakephp-3)

[How to solve cakephp 500 Internal Server Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19893132/how-to-solve-cakephp-500-internal-server-error)

[CakePHP 500 Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22242863/cakephp-500-internal-server-error)

[CakePHP shows 500 Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20092289/cakephp-shows-500-internal-server-error)

My .htaccess code in /root/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

In /root/app/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

In /root/app/webroot/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This error is still coming after a lot of effort.

[image: Screen Shot]

Please Help?

Comment: Found any solutions? Having the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may not be a problem everytime. Your .htaccess code may be alright. Please check permission of your root folder on godaddy server. It dependent on which type of server you use. Please enable to your folder permission on server. Then it may be working for you.